# SearchBar with scope layout bug in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I just updated Xcode, and testing my app on iOS 8 for the first time. It works great, except for a weird bug with a SearchBar, which is merged with the scope bar (see below).

[image: screenshot]

This also appears on my storyboard, in Xcode.

I think it maybe appears because I am still on Mavericks, and I probably don't have an iOS 8 simulator (it doesn't appear in the Xcode downloaded components), but my simulator clearly mentions that iOS 8 is used.

Do you have this problem ?

Pierre

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix on the iOS Developer Forums...

Just add this to `viewDidLoad`

```
_searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 88);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but I saw several posts giving this solution. I think (and hope) this bug is due to the fact that I'm still on Mavericks (and have no mention of iOS 8 in my storyboard or in my list of emulators).

Comment: @Pierre I'm on mavericks too and I don't think thats the issue. It's not only the simulator it also happens on devices, even in apps not targeting iOS 8. Clearly it's an iOS bug, this solution should work are you sure you're referencing the same search bar linked in Storyboard?